# Text inserted in the dropdown field is not reflecting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown where an other option is there,when other option is selected a new field comes up where we can input the text specifying other,BUt when text is filled iam not getting the data filled in the field am only getting other

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function showfield(name){
   if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
   else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select name="drop" id="drop" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="bike">bike</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div1"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And how put a help text which will go away when we are inserting the data inside the new text box that is coming when other is selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using jquery is easier for such things

Answer (score 2):

Try this its working for you

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function showfield(name){
    var name=document.getElementById("drop").value;
    if(name=='Other'){
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
        }
        else {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
        }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select name="drop" id="drop" onchange="showfield()">
  <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="bike">bike</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div1"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i print or insert in db when i echo it back i only see "other" but not the value typed in text field..Please help

Comment: code work for you when you select other option in dropdown it display the input field

Answer (score 1):

Remove onchange event from the select tag.

```
var select = document.getElementById('drop');

select.addEventListener("change", processEvent, false);

function processEvent() {
  var name = this.value;
  if(name == 'Other') {
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text"   name="other" />';
  } else {
     document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML= name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using innerHTML, the previously entered values will be cleared, to avoid that, you can append the input element as follows:

```
var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text"; 
input.name="other" 
document.getElelmentById('div1').appendChild(input);
```